# UITableView Sections from an array of Objects (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, object, sections

I’ve got an array of Transaction objects:

```
var transactions = [Transaction]()
```

Transaction class:

```
class Transaction {
    var description : String = ""
    var post_transaction_balance : Double = 0
    var settlement_date : NSDate?
    var dateOnly : NSDate?
 }
```

I need to create a UITableView with sections and each section represents transactions made on particular day

An example of how table structure should look like:

— section header: dateOnly—

transaction [0] title

transaction [3] title

— section header: dateOnly—

transaction [2] title

transaction [7] title

Example of dateOnly value:

```
dateOnly = (NSDate?) 2016-01-22 00:00:00 UTC
```

I am not sure how to iterate through the array of objects and get the data into the section headers and the cells. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: All date contain same time `00:00:00 UTC` ?

Comment: @NDoc yes, thank you

Answer (score 5):

**Preview of the result:**

[image]

Note: I have used Swift 3.

**ViewController:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak private var tableView: UITableView!
  var transactionsGroupedByDate = [(String,Array<Transaction>)]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    getTransactions()
  }

  // Getting transactions
  private func getTransactions() {
    let transactions = makeTransactions()
    self.transactionsGroupedByDate = groupByDate(transactions: transactions)

    tableView.reloadData()
  }

  // Grouping the transactions by their date
  private func groupByDate(transactions: [Transaction]) -> [(String,Array<Transaction>)] {
    var transactionsGroupedByDate = Dictionary<String, Array<Transaction>>()

    // Looping the Array of transactions
    for transaction in transactions {

      // Converting the transaction's date to String
      let date = convertDateToString(date: transaction.date!)

      // Verifying if the array is nil for the current date used as a
      // key in the dictionary, if so the array is initialized only once
      if transactionsGroupedByDate[date] == nil {
        transactionsGroupedByDate[date] = Array<Transaction>()
      }

      // Adding the transaction in the dictionary to the key that is the date
      transactionsGroupedByDate[date]?.append(transaction)
    }

    // Sorting the dictionary to descending order and the result will be
    // an array of tuples with key(String) and value(Array<Transaction>)
    return transactionsGroupedByDate.sorted { $0.0 > $1.0 }
  }
}
```

---

**Helper Methods:**

```
extension ViewController {
  // Helper to create a date formatter
  func createDateFormatter() -> DateFormatter {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")

    return dateFormatter
  }

  // Helper to convert date to string
  func convertDateToString(date: Date) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = createDateFormatter()

    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
  }

  // Mocking the transactions
  func makeTransactions() -> [Transaction] {
    var transactions = [Transaction]()

    let dateFormatter = createDateFormatter()

    let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-01-22 00:00:00")
    let transaction1 = Transaction(title: "transaction 1", date: date1)

    let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-01-22 00:00:00")
    let transaction2 = Transaction(title: "transaction 2", date: date2)

    let date3 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-01-23 00:00:00")
    let transaction3 = Transaction(title: "transaction 3", date: date3)

    let date4 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-01-24 00:00:00")
    let transaction4 = Transaction(title: "transaction 4", date: date4)

    let date5 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-01-24 00:00:00")
    let transaction5 = Transaction(title: "transaction 5", date: date5)

    let date6 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-01-25 00:00:00")
    let transaction6 = Transaction(title: "transaction 6", date: date6)

    transactions.append(transaction1)
    transactions.append(transaction2)
    transactions.append(transaction3)
    transactions.append(transaction4)
    transactions.append(transaction5)
    transactions.append(transaction6)

    return transactions
  }
}
```

---

**UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource methods:**

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return transactionsGroupedByDate[section].1.count
  }

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return transactionsGroupedByDate.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return transactionsGroupedByDate[section].0
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let transaction = transactionsGroupedByDate[indexPath.section].1[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = transaction.title

    return cell
  }
}
```

---

**Transaction struct:**

```
struct Transaction {
  var title: String?
  var date: Date?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not reorganize the array to a dictionary.

You can enumerate the transaction array and save it as [String: Transaction]. The key could be your particular day's description.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `section` array (i.e. `[Int:NSDate]`) containing the starting index of each section & date value (section title) of each section.

You can define a `func` filling the section array and might do the following in it:

1. Reorder your `transactions` array according to `dateOnly` objects in it, so that the `Transaction` object with the closest date will be at top.
2. Iterate the sorted array to find `dateOnly` objects that are different from that of previous object in the array and put these `dateOnly` objects in section array.

Now, you have a `section` array containing the `dateOnly` objects, and a sorted `Transaction` array. You can easily use these for populating the `tableView`.